# Why does bash think: 016 + 1 = 15?

Tags: bash

Can somebody explain to me why a number with a leading 0 gives this funny behaviour?

```
#!/bin/bash
NUM=016 
SUM=$((NUM + 1)) 
echo "$NUM + 1 = $SUM"
```

Will print:

> 016 + 1 = 15

Comment: Psst: `printf "%03d\n" 10` is completely usable in bash to obtain a leading zero for filenames and such.

Comment: @Squeezy Thanks, but that part was already working. The actual problem was not obtaining a filename with a leading 0. It was finding out what the filename was with the highest number and then creating the next-in-sequence, by using printf "prefix-%03d.tif" $SUM.

Comment: Note that you could've figured this out yourself just by doing `echo $((016))`

Comment: FYI, this is true in many programming languages: C, C++, Javascript.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The misunderstanding is that the numbers don't mean what you expect.

A leading zero denotes a number with base 8. I.e. `016` is the same as `8#16`. If you want to keep the leading zero then you need `10#016`.

```
> num=016
> echo $((num))
14
> echo $((10#$num))
16
```

Comment: There are 10 types of people in the world. Those who understand binary, those who don't, those who weren't expecting a base 8 joke, and 5 other types of people.

Answer (score 42):

Because:

```
~$ echo $((NUM))
14
```

if the number begins with 0, it is considered to be an octal value and 16 in octal is 14 in decimal.

Comment: That makes perfectly sence and explains why my script was overwriting my old files :-(